# Strange equality error with PyMongo-flask

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo, flask-pymongo

So I have this api endpoint:

```
@app.route("/subject", methods=["GET"])
def GET_subject():
    subject = request.args["subject"]
    page = int(request.args["page"])

    pagesize = 10
    subjectResults = db.subject.find()[pagesize*(page-1):pagesize*(page)]
    if subjectResults is "[]":
        return json.dumps({"page": page, "subject": subject, "subjectResults": bson.json_util.dumps(subjectResults)})
    else:
        return json.dumps({"error": "404"})
```

and when I run it, with no data in the database, it returns the error 404 message I put in. As you can tell, I'm using Flask and Flask-PyMongo for this.

Comment: What is your if statement supposed to be doing? The result will never be that string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the `is` keyword, you are comparing identity of objects.

In your case, you are checking if `subjectResults` is the same object as string literal `"[]"`, which will always be `False`.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is-in-python) for explanation on the `is` keyword.